# Should a new interface be created if it doesn't add anything to the contract (yet)?

Tags: java, design-patterns, object-oriented-design

I'm writing an API for a bunch of different aspects of my project. I have some code that currently looks like

```
interface LoginCredentialRepository {

    Callable<LoginCredential> fetchCredentials(String username);
}
```

I had the thought to add a new interface to the mix, a `FetchLoginCredentialTask` that looked something like

```
interface FetchLoginCredentialsTask extends Callable<LoginCredential> {

}
```

and change `fetchCredentials` to

```
FetchLoginCredentialsTask fetchCredentials(String username);
```

Whereby the new interface doesn't actually change anything at the moment (but maybe could in the future).

What reason would there be to do something like this?

Comment: If you were to tell me just `FetchLoginCredentialsTask`, I would assume this to be an object, not an interface.

Comment: "Whereby the new interface doesn't actually change anything at the moment (but maybe could in the future)." Then add it in the future, when it's needed. If it's not used now, then it's redundant code and thus it makes it harder to understand.

Comment: I agree with David. The only reason where I think doing what you are asking is reasonable is if you've already worked on a similar system and "your thought" is almost certain to become a reality and "your thought" is already tried and proven for solving the problem "your thought" is explicitly taking care of. From the wording in your question, it seems like you are guessing at solving a yet unknown problem. Thus, when the real problem occurs, it is extremely likely that it won't be the same problem as the unknown problem, which means that you'll need a different solution anyways.